# Do not have onBackPressed close app in Android?

Tags: android

So I'm want to use onBackPressed as an option to go back to the main activity when clicked, however, my current set up just has it closing the app.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onBackPressed()`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   Log.d("CDA", "onBackPressed Called");
   //call you activity here.
}
```

Or alternatively `onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        //call you activity here.
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!  Accepting the answer as soon as it lets me.